# How to match up Amazon CloudSearch document update error with document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Amazon CloudSearch (at least v2) provides errors and warnings like:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "warnings": [{
        "message": "Multi-valued field \"color\" has no value (near operation with index 949)"
    },
    {
        "message": "Multi-valued field \"color_id\" has no value (near operation with index 949)"
    }],
    "adds": 1000,
    "deletes": 0
}
```

where the only way to figure out which document had an issue is parsing the *"near operation with index X"* and plucking that index.

I've seen [a post somewhere that seems to indicate it can return `document_id` as well](https://sagebionetworks.jira.com/browse/PLFM-2585), but I'm not sure where that comes from.

So my question has two parts:

1. How can CloudSearch return the document id in the error/warning message?
2. If #1 isn't possible, is the CloudSearch error/warning message index 0- or 1-based?

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial confirmation based on limited testing -- seems like the index is 1-based.

Meaning "near operation with index 949" refers to `documents[948]`.

Knowing that, I can back-reference into the document list to append its id to the error message.